# How to get the latest build-tools version with the cli Android sdkmanager?

Tags: android, dockerfile, android-sdk-manager

I'm trying to automate our build process using Docker.

I've hard coded `ANDROID_API_LEVELS` and `ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION` but I would like to always get the latest versions to pass it to `sdkmanager` executable.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
# ANDROID SDK DOCKER IMAGE
# ===================================================================== #

# HARD ENV VERSIONS
# --------------------------------------------------------------------- #
ENV ANDROID_API_LEVELS android-26
ENV ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION 26.0.2
ENV ANDROID_HOME /opt/android-sdk
ENV PATH ${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/bin:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools

# REQUIREMENTS
# --------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# support multiarch: i386 architecture
# install Java
# install essential tools
# install Qt
RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386 && \
    apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y libncurses5:i386 libc6:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5 lib32z1 zlib1g:i386 && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openjdk-8-jdk && \
    apt-get install -y git wget zip curl && \
    apt-get install -y qt5-default

# ANDROID
# --------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# install latest android sdk
RUN ANDROID_SDK_URL=$( \
  curl -s https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html | \
        grep 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-[0-9]*[.zip]' | \
        head -n 1 | \
        cut -d '"' -f 2 \
  ) && \
  mkdir -p ${ANDROID_HOME} && cd ${ANDROID_HOME} && \
  wget -q ${ANDROID_SDK_URL} && \
  unzip *tools*linux*.zip && \
  rm *tools*linux*.zip  

# install Android modules
RUN sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;${ANDROID_API_LEVELS}" "build-tools;{$ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION}"
RUN sdkmanager "extras;android;m2repository" "extras;google;m2repository" "extras;google;google_play_services"
RUN sdkmanager "extras;google;webdriver"
```

How do I get the latest `build-tools` and `platforms` version?